# How to load data from server using HTTP POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a registration form that will register the user and let the user know if the account has been activated or not.
I have a function that will load data from the server using an HTTP POST request.

```
function ajaxRegisterUser(registerUserInfo) {
    alert($.param(registerUserInfo));
    $.post(serverUrl + "Account/RegisterUser?" + $.param(registerUserInfo),
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
}
```

The alert will display the form input but I cannot seem to get the function to fire...It never makes it to alert(data). Is there something that I am missing here?
Accepting any and all feedback.  Thanks.  :)

Here is the registerUser function that gets the values:

```
function registerUser() {

    var username = $('#register_username').val();
    var email = $('#register_email').val();
    var password = $('#register_password').val();

    var registerUserInfo = {
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
    }

    ajaxRegisterUser(registerUserInfo);
}
```

Comment: Check the browser console for errors, and observe the network tab for failing requests. Also, does this line show an alert -- `alert($.param(registerUserInfo));`?

Comment: You can extract server url you are constructing into variable to check for obvious mistakes like missing slashes etc.
So something like `var url = serverUrl + "Account/RegisterUser?" + $.param(registerUserInfo)`

Comment: yeah using the alert for testing...it displays the contents of the submitted form.

Comment: Typically, you would set a request body for POST requests. You appear to be setting all the data in the query string. Perhaps you want `$.post(serverUrl + "Account/RegisterUser", registerUserInfo, function(data) { ... })`

Comment: It's not typical to post with url parameters. They may not be well formed

Comment: true, the $.getJSON method is much easier to work with than $.post

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned but still cannot hit the function and alert(data).